# How to temporarily pause PayPal subscriptions while preserving remaining time?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I would like to be able to pause my customers' PayPal subscriptions and then resume them. I also want them not to lose the remaining time in a subscription cycle. I wonder how can I achieve that?

I considered using the `/billing/subscriptions/:subscription_id/suspend` endpoint [(see docs)](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/multiparty/subscriptions/customize/pause-resume/). But I am unsure what exactly happens when the subscription is in a SUSPENDED status during its `billing_info.next_billing_time`. Will the buyer be charged immediately after it's resumed, or the next billing time will be postponed by one cycle, or the behavior is even different?

Answer (score 0):

#### Consideration:

There will be several scenarios you might want to consider:

1. The client paused their subscription
2. The client did not pay their bill several times

#### Scenario 1:

we should ensure the customers do not lose the remaining time in their subscription cycle, you would ideally want the resumed subscription to pick up where it left off. It might be controlled by your PayPal subscription configuration or API parameters. Ensure that you set up your subscriptions to support this behaviour if it's important for your business model.

#### Scenario 2

The customer should be charged immediately after it's resumed.

---

Hope it helps